# apache, mercury32, php mail. Can't get it to work

Tags: php, php-ini

I can not get PHP mail to send email...

All this is just to test my php mail function in my localhost setup. XAMPP-apache,mercury,mysql,windowXP

I am pretty sure I installed mercury 32 correct, If i use it to send an email to root@localhost.com it works fine, i see it sent and in my thunderbird inbox i set up for it.

php.ini is where I get a bit confused

```
[mail function]
;---- I left this as is(out), since I AM using Mercury
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
;---- I created a root user in mercury
sendmail_from = root@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesD:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the D:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;---- I left this as is(in), but I feel it should be commented out, but if I take out i get error in pho mail() code
sendmail_path = "D:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

---

PHP CODE for mail();

```
   .....
   $mailSubject   = "Hello there!!!";
   $mailFrom      = "From: me123@gamil.com" . "\r\n";
   $mailTo        = "root@localhost.com";

   if (mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailMessage, $mailFrom)){
      echo("Message successfully sent! $mailTo");
   } 
   else {
      echo("Message delivery failed...");
   }
```

The mails gets sent, but to where? i can never find it

Some images:
**testing Mercury. Went to "file>Send mail message" to get this screen and created an email to test**
[image: testing Mercury. Went to "file>Send mail message" to get this screen and created an email to test]

**client email inbox- result of the above image/test**
[image: client email inbox- result of the above image/test]

**Script output in browser**
[image: screen output]

Comment: your mail function is correct from such a glance. Is a delivery failure error being printed? Perhaps you have some other error. No other idea

Comment: mercury is most likely keeping logs, check those out; should give you a little more insight.

Comment: nothing meaningful in MERCURYS.LOG

Answer (score 0):

(first: sorry for my poor english)
To solutionate this, I configured php.ini and sendmail.ini like this:

php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP = 127.0.0.1
 smtp_port = 25
 sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
;sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\ -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

And the sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

;smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com

smtp_server=localhost
```

Remember to comment the sendmail_path on PHP.ini
Now It's working for me :)